# Fowarding freeradius

Tags: freeradius, radius

I am a complete beginner in freeradius and I need to configure a server so that it communicates with another radius. My question is how does such a configuration work, how to configure freeradius as a proxy to send Authentication and Accounting forwarding to another Radius.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: A very old question, but if it it's still relevant to you, you'd like get more help on the site in the same family serverfault.com